# Javascript injection overriding CSS for responsive slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I'm using Cycle Slider by Malsup and I'm having some trouble with the injection of inline CSS styles.

If you navigate to http://cirrusfitness.com you will see I have the slider working and functional.

The ISSUE comes into play when you resize the browser to test for responsiveness. It appears after the 980px breakpoint, the image seems to shrink disproportionately to the container. Leaving a tiny image and a large white space.

I have tried using CSS background-size: cover as well as applying fixed h/w ratios to the .item class but have had no luck.

Any help would be great..

Comment: Essentially trying to get the image to fill the space all the way down to the three circle pager nav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only seems to be a problem when you are actively re-sizing the browser window with your mouse. This plugin seems to be putting an inline style with a static height on the `#hompage-slider_content` when it loads.  When you scale you browser window down past the 980px mark then reload the page you'll notice you won't have that massive white space anymore because the plugin will calculate the right height when it loads.

To fix this you may have to attach an event to the window resize event and update the `#hompage-slider_content` with a new inline height.

Comment: Refreshing does remove some of the white space. What I am looking to do is fill the white space between the image and the pager dot navigation for the slider. If you inspect element you see the image is not taking up the full container.

Comment: This appears to be because of the inline style `background-size` the plugin is putting on your div slides

Comment: zgood -- really appreciate you looking into this for me. I am aware that it seems this injection is the issue. No idea how to remedy it though?

Comment: You could try adding this to your css `#hompage-slider_content .item{ background-size: cover !important;  }`

Comment: it seems the change only happens after resizing the browser lower than 960. Before that, the background-size is set to auto.

Comment: Are you using the Cycle2 plugin?

Comment: I believe I'm using an older version.. got stuck inheriting a site from an old developer. I implemented the code you said and it worked as I had expected / wanted to. Only issue now is the image runs off the screen. Is there maybe something else I can add in?

 * jQuery Cycle Plugin (with Transition Definitions)
 * Examples and documentation at: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/
 * Copyright (c) 2007-2010 M. Alsup
 * Version: 2.9999.5 (10-APR-2012)

Comment: `background-size: 100% 100%` maybe what you want then... but it may skew your images

Comment: ZGOOD FOR THE WIN!!! I did the 100%, 100% and you're correct it did skew my images but its all good now I know what was handling it. Thank you so much!

Comment: no prob. It gets tricky because aspect ratio will change (when you resize the window the height stays the same but the width changes) which is why it gets skewed at `100% 100%` whereas cover will clip the image so it fills the whole space in the new aspect ratio

Answer (score 0):

Using #hompage-slider_content .item{ background-size: cover !important; } I was able to fill the aspect ratio but this made some of the image overflow.

To fix this I used background-size: 100% 100% which filled the height and width. This will skew the image but is better than having large areas of white space.